# windows 7 cmd - use alias for jruby on rails

Tags: windows, cmd, alias

The "rails" command can be executed in jruby/bin folder only. I want to create my applications in other folder.

For example:

```
C:/jruby/Projects/
```

But in this folder the "rails" command is not recognized. Is there a way to create some kind of alias which I can used do to somethings like that:

```
C:/jruby/Projects/alliasname rails
```

Comment: `DOSKEY` lets you create aliases (macros). Will those do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `jruby/bin` folder to your PATH environment variable. But be sure to actually add the *full* path.

Simply search in the start menu for "env" and then edit the `PATH` variable:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. One more thing I want to ask: is there a way for example to have and other PATH variable that will point to other files or just one?

Comment: The PATH environment variable contains a semicolon-separated list of paths that are searched for commands that are unqualified with a path. So every executable in those paths will be found.